# Extraño bug en web mostrada en chrome, imágenes adjuntas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

**HOLA COMUNIDAD!**

No fui más preciso en el título porque me cuesta describir el tipo de error que se presenta, nunca antes lo había visto y no puedo rescatar ningún dato ni de los logs ni de la dev console. 
Pienso que podría ser un conflicto con los archivos .js. 
El error sucede sólo a veces, puedo estar navegando bien en el sitio durante todo el día y al día siguiente al abrirlo sucede nuevamente. 
Por esto mismo no puedo asegurar si el error sucede sólo en chrome porque es el navegador que más uso y por ende en el que he advertido el error esporádico. Al abrir el sitio en otros navegadores a simple vista no acontece el fallo y tampoco se levantan excepciones.

El sitio web lo tengo alojado en wordpress.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se ve en las imágenes es intermitente, se van alternando los *desencajes estéticos* (no sé cómo llamarlo) de un lugar a otro de la página, parpadeante y pseudoaleatorio.

---

Mi archivo main.js:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var textWrapper = $('.ml3')[0];
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
    anime.timeline({loop: false})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml3 .letter',
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeInOutQuad",
    duration: 1050,
    delay: (el, i) => 30 * (i+1)
  })
    var textWrapper2 = $('.ml2')[0];
    textWrapper2.innerHTML = textWrapper2.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
    anime.timeline({loop: false})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml2 .letter',
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeInOutQuad",
    duration: 1050,
    delay: (el, i) => 5 * (i+1)
  })
    /*.add({
    targets: '.ml3',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });*/
});
jQuery(function($) {
  function getOffset(elem) {
    var offsetLeft = 0, offsetTop = 0;
    do {
      if ( !isNaN( elem.offsetLeft ) )
      {
        offsetLeft += elem.offsetLeft;
        offsetTop += elem.offsetTop;
      }
    } while( elem = elem.offsetParent );
    return {left: offsetLeft, top: offsetTop};
  }

  var targets = document.querySelectorAll( '[rel=tooltip]' ),
  target  = false,
  tooltip = false,
  title   = false,
  tip     = false;

  for(var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    targets[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
      target  = this;
      tip     = target.getAttribute("title");
      tooltip = document.createElement("div");
      tooltip.id = "tooltip";

      if(!tip || tip == "")
      return false;

      target.removeAttribute("title");
      tooltip.style.opacity = 0;
      tooltip.innerHTML = tip;
      document.body.appendChild(tooltip);

      var init_tooltip = function()
      {
        console.log(getOffset(target));
        // set width of tooltip to half of window width
        if(window.innerWidth < tooltip.offsetWidth * 1.5)
        tooltip.style.maxWidth = window.innerWidth / 2;
        else
        tooltip.style.maxWidth = 340;

        var pos_left = getOffset(target).left + (target.offsetWidth / 2) - (tooltip.offsetWidth / 2),
        pos_top  = getOffset(target).top - tooltip.offsetHeight - 10;
        console.log("top is", pos_top);
        if( pos_left < 0 )
        {
          pos_left = getOffset(target).left + target.offsetWidth / 2 - 20;
          tooltip.classList.add("left");
        }
        else
        tooltip.classList.remove("left");

        if( pos_left + tooltip.offsetWidth > window.innerWidth )
        {
          pos_left = getOffset(target).left - tooltip.offsetWidth + target.offsetWidth / 2 + 20;
          tooltip.classList.add("right");
        }
        else
        tooltip.classList.remove("right");

        if( pos_top < 0 )
        {
          var pos_top  = getOffset(target).top + target.offsetHeight + 15;
          tooltip.classList.add("top");
        }
        else
        tooltip.classList.remove("top");
        // adding "px" is very important
        tooltip.style.left = pos_left + "px";
        tooltip.style.top = pos_top + "px";
        tooltip.style.opacity  = 1;
      };

      init_tooltip();
      window.addEventListener("resize", init_tooltip);

      var remove_tooltip = function() {
        tooltip.style.opacity  = 0;
        document.querySelector("#tooltip") && document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector("#tooltip"));
        target.setAttribute("title", tip );
      };

      target.addEventListener("mouseleave", remove_tooltip );
      tooltip.addEventListener("click", remove_tooltip );
    });
  }

});
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        "use strict";
        var nav = $('nav');
        var navHeight = nav.outerHeight();
        $('.navbar-toggler').on('click', function() {
            if( ! $('#mainNav').hasClass('navbar-reduce')) {
            $('#mainNav').addClass('navbar-reduce');
            }
        })
        // Back to top button
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
            $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
        $('.back-to-top').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
            return false;
        });
            /*--/ Star Scrolling nav /--*/
            $('a.js-scroll[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').on("click", function () {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                    var target = $(this.hash);
                    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                    if (target.length) {
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: (target.offset().top - navHeight + 5)
                        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
            $('.js-scroll').on("click", function () {
                $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
            });

            // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
            $('body').scrollspy({
                target: '#mainNav',
                offset: navHeight
            });
            /*--/ End Scrolling nav /--*/

            /*--/ Navbar Menu Reduce /--*/
            $(window).trigger('scroll');
            $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                var pixels = 50; 
                var top = 1200;
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > pixels) {
                    $('.navbar-expand-md').addClass('navbar-reduce');
                    $('.navbar-expand-md').removeClass('navbar-trans');
                } else {
                    $('.navbar-expand-md').addClass('navbar-trans');
                    $('.navbar-expand-md').removeClass('navbar-reduce');
                }
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > top) {
                    $('.scrolltop-mf').fadeIn(1000, "easeInOutExpo");
                } else {
                    $('.scrolltop-mf').fadeOut(1000, "easeInOutExpo");
                }
            });

            if ($('.text-slider').length == 1) {
            var typed_strings = $('.text-slider-items').text();
                var typed = new Typed('.text-slider', {
                    strings: typed_strings.split(','),
                    typeSpeed: 1800,
                    loop: false,
                });
            }

    });
});
```

Archivo functions.php con los archivos .js:

```
<?php
//Load jQuery
function loadjQuery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.min.js', array(), 2);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

//Load js
function add_js(){
    wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), 40);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
    wp_register_script('jqueryMigrate', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/jquery-migrate.min.js", array('jquery'), null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jqueryMigrate'); 
    wp_register_script('jquery.counterup', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/jquery.counterup.min.js", array('jquery'), null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.counterup');
    wp_register_script('jqueryWaypoints', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js", array('jquery'), null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jqueryWaypoints');   
    wp_register_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/easing.min.js", array('jquery'), null);
    wp_enqueue_script('easing');    
    wp_register_script('anime', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js", array('jquery'), 13);
    wp_enqueue_script('anime');
    wp_register_script('main', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js', array('jquery'), 61);
    wp_enqueue_script('main');


}

?>
```

Se me olvidó mencionar algo importante: 
Tras cerrar la ventana, el error perdura por algunos segundos **en el resto de las pestañas del navegador.**

Les agradezco mucho de antemano, 
Saludos!!

Comment: Estas usando linux?, a mi a vecez me pasa en ubuntu, mas frecuentemente en chrome cosas extrañas pero normalmente solo me pasan en linux... en windows no me pasan.

Comment: En la pestaña network no te aparece un 404? puede que sencillamente no lo encuentre, un problema de carga, revisa en la pestaña source del chrome dev y verifica que esten los archivos que encolas en wordpress

Comment: puede ser también que sea un error de lógica, una condición que no se cumpla en ciertas ocasiones  y por eso no genera un error en consola.

Comment: No Michel, lamentablemente tampoco se arroja error en network.

Comment: Riven, efectivamente estoy usando linux ahora, pero si no recuerdo mal también vi este error en win (estuve trabajando en windows hace poco)... Haré unas pruebas y te aviso, gracias por el dato

Comment: ¿Qué aparece cuando inspeccionas los elementos cuando hay error?

Comment: Nada, no muestra ningún tipo de mensaje